# Android SQLiteStatement Insert, nothing happen

Tags: android, soap, insert, android-sqlite

i have some data from SoapObject, i want insert to sqlite, for better performance, i use the following code :

```
public void testInsert(String sql, SoapObject rs, int index) {
        try {
            sql = "INSERT INTO NSPMasterHarga (KdBarang, Wilayah, HargaJual1, HargaJual2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            theDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
            theDatabase.beginTransaction();

            String drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NSPMasterHarga";
            SQLiteStatement stmtDrop = theDatabase.compileStatement(drop);
            stmtDrop.execute();

            String create = "CREATE TABLE NSPMasterHarga (KdBarang TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Wilayah TEXT, HargaJual1 TEXT, HargaJual2 TEXT)";
            SQLiteStatement stmtCreate = theDatabase.compileStatement(create);
            stmtCreate.execute();

            SQLiteStatement stmt = theDatabase.compileStatement(sql);

            int count = rs.getPropertyCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                SoapObject row = (SoapObject) rs.getProperty(i);

                for (int j = 1; j <= index; j++) {
                    stmt.bindString(j, row.getProperty(j - 1).toString().replace("anyType{}", ""));
                }

                long entryID = stmt.executeInsert();
                stmt.clearBindings();
            }
        /*for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++) {
            //generate some values

            stmt.bindString(1, randomName);
            stmt.bindString(2, randomDescription);
            stmt.bindDouble(3, randomPrice);
            stmt.bindLong(4, randomNumber);

            long entryID = stmt.executeInsert();
            stmt.clearBindings();
        }*/

            theDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
            theDatabase.endTransaction();

            theDatabase.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String err = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

When debug, i've got nothing error, but the data not insert to my sqlite.
Any idea or clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this code inside a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: inside .. @Tobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for better performance

I'm not so sure which part of the code you are referring to. Opening and closing the database after each interaction is **terrible** for performance. The SQLiteOpenHelper takes care of all this, so you don't need to do anything manually.

Try the following alternative to insert an entry:

```
public boolean addEntry(){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("column1", "value1");  // make sure the type corresponds to your sql column type
    values.put("column2", "value2");
    values.put("column3", "value3");
    values.put("column4Int", 1);

    long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    Log.d("DBHelper", "Added row " + newRowId + " to DB.");

    return newRowId != -1;  // -1 means it failed
}
```

Comment: is this func i placed inside loop SoapObject ? where i place table name ? :/ looks like this only column name. Thanks

Comment: Your table name is "NSPMasterHarga". Inside ContentValues you have one entry per column. As in the example `values.put("column1", "value1")`.  Yes you place inside the outer for loop. And you do not need the inner for loop. But first test a sample before trying to solve the soap